# How to use a .Net framework package with AWS Lambda

Tags: c#, .net, docker, aws-lambda

Im trying to deploy a function that has a package only available in .Net framework and found out I can only get .net framework working if I deploy as a docker container.

But the container code still also relies on the package `Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson`  , which is only available on .netcore so I cant install it using nuget. The line below is still required for container images:

```
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer))]
```

How is this supposed to work?

Comment: .NET framework isn't supported on Lambda, AFAIK, so there's no way to run it. Containers have to be Linux. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html

Comment: @HansKilian `As part of that release, we updated the AWS Lambda .NET tooling to support building Lambda functions as container images for .NET Core 2.1 and 3.1, as well as full support for .NET 5.` This is from AWS, I thought it meant now .net framework can also run?

Comment: I don't think so. .NET 5 is basically .NET core 5. They just dropped the 'core' name. Core is multi-platform. Framework is Windows only and is not being actively developed anymore.

Comment: @HansKilian Ah got it. Okay thanks